# Increment a custom environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, increment

I created a windows custom environment variable with setx (i tested it, it works) and i would like to increment it each time i start a batch file (and sometimes, reset it to 0).

My first idea, following other classic languages, was :

```
%myVariable% = %myVariable% + 1
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
echo %NEWVAR%
```

similar question https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt

to be accurate use `set /a myVariable = %myVariable% + 1`

http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

> Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)
>
> include the following operators:The expression to be evaluated can

**You need to initialize it first**

```
set /a myVariable=0
```

Examples to increment:

- `set /a myVariable=%myVariable% + 1`
- `set /a "myVariable+=1"`

Comment: I tested set /a myVariable+=1 but it doesn't worked :'(

Comment: try set /a myVariable =%myVariable% + 1

Comment: my variable is still at 0 even with set /a myVariable = %myVariable% + 1. I created it with setx MyVariable 0, and it looks like i can't change the value inside :S

Comment: I found a solution using a non-environement variable : set myVariable = _GlobalVariable
set /a "myVariable+=1"
setx _GlobalVariable %myVariable%

Comment: you need to initialize it first

Comment: Show the entire block of code in which you are using it. You may have it inside an IF statement of FOR loop, or inside a group of statements enclosed by parens.